# Class not found when extending vendor class in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to override method from vendor class.

My `CustomEditable.php` class

```
<?php

namespace App\Custom;

class CustomEditable extends \Encore\Admin\Grid\Displayers\Editable
{
    /**
     * Number type editable.
     */
    public function number()
    {
        dd("OK");
    }
}
```

Then, in my `AppServiceProvider.php` I have

```
public function register()
{
    $loader = \Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader::getInstance();
    $loader->alias(\Encore\Admin\Grid\Displayers\Editable::class, \App\Custom\CustomEditable::class);
}
```

I think my custom class is loading well, but he cant find vendor class. Got this error:

[image]

Comment: You're aliasing `\Encore\Admin\Grid\Displayers\Editable::class` to `\App\Custom\CustomEditable::class` but the `CustomEditable` class is referring to  `Editable` class. That looks like circular logic. I suggest you find a better way of solving whatever it is you're trying to solve here

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks for your response. It makes sense. My goal is to override \Encore\Admin\Grid\Displayers\Editable::class method, so I created my CustomEditable::class and I extend original class. My question is how can I tell to Laravel whenever \Encore\Admin\Grid\Displayers\Editable::class is called, go to my CustomClass with overrided method instead of the original.

Comment: In an ideal world you would not need to. In this particular case in https://github.com/z-song/laravel-admin/blob/be095f535b7add13e9a70c44b6b84a2f8518d96f/src/Grid/Column.php there's the  `public static function extend($name, $displayer)` which you could *possibly* just call as `Column::extend('editable', CustomClass::class)`

Comment: @apokryfos yea, you are right. It can be done that way but im trying to do as extending vendor class because some classes cant be extended like this particular case.

Comment: Again in an ideal world you'd fork the library and modify the classes you want and include your own modified fork in your project. If it's something that could be of general use you could even send a pull request to have your changes included in the library. In a less than ideal world you can [register your own autoloader](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) before the composer one is registered (e.g. in `index.php`) and load your file when the other file is about to be autoloaded